# Array index 74 is out of bounds (overflow) google big query

Tags: google-bigquery

In Big Query, I was having issues moving a Pipe(|)-delimited file into Google Big Query.  To make this work, I decided to bring in each line whole as a single string, and then perform the `SPLIT` function to get the fields I want in the data types I need it in.

In this case, I have this `SELECT` statement:

```
Select
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(0)] as INT64) AS FIELD1
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(1)] AS FIELD2
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(2)] AS FIELD3
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(3)] AS FIELD4
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(4)] AS FIELD5
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(5)] AS FIELD6
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(6)] as timestamp) AS FIELD7
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(7)] AS FIELD8
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(8)] AS FIELD9
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(9)] AS FIELD10
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(10)] AS FIELD11
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(11)] AS FIELD12
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(12)] AS FIELD13
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(13)] AS FIELD14
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(14)] AS FIELD15
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(15)] AS FIELD16
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(16)] AS FIELD17
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(17)] AS FIELD18
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(18)] AS FIELD19
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(19)] AS FIELD20
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(20)] AS FIELD21
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(21)] AS FIELD22
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(22)] AS FIELD23
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(23)] AS FIELD24
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(24)] AS FIELD25
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(25)] AS FIELD26
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(26)] AS FIELD27
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(27)] as INT64) AS FIELD28
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(28)] AS FIELD29
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(29)] AS FIELD30
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(30)] AS FIELD31
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(31)] as timestamp) AS FIELD32
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(32)] as INT64) AS FIELD33
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(33)] as INT64) AS FIELD34
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(34)] as timestamp) AS FIELD35
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(35)] as INT64) AS FIELD36
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(36)] as INT64) AS FIELD37
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(37)] as timestamp) AS FIELD38
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(38)] as numeric) AS FIELD39
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(39)] as INT64) AS FIELD40
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(40)] as INT64) AS FIELD41
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(41)] AS FIELD42
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(42)] AS FIELD43
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(43)] as INT64) AS FIELD44
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(44)] as numeric) AS FIELD45
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(45)] AS FIELD46
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(46)] as timestamp) AS FIELD47
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(47)] AS FIELD48
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(48)] as INT64) AS FIELD49
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(49)] as timestamp) AS FIELD50
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(50)] as INT64) AS FIELD51
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(51)] as INT64) AS FIELD52
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(52)] as INT64) AS FIELD53
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(53)] as INT64) AS FIELD54
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(54)] as timestamp) AS FIELD55
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(55)] as INT64) AS FIELD56
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(56)] as timestamp) AS FIELD57
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(57)] AS FIELD58
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(58)] AS FIELD59
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(59)] AS FIELD60
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(60)] AS FIELD61
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(61)] AS FIELD62
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(62)] AS FIELD63
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(63)] as FLOAT64) AS FIELD64
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(64)] as FLOAT64) AS FIELD65
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(65)] AS FIELD66
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(66)] as INT64) AS FIELD67
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(67)] as INT64) AS FIELD68
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(68)] as INT64) AS FIELD69
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(69)] AS FIELD70
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(70)] AS FIELD71
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(71)] AS FIELD72
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(72)] as timestamp) AS FIELD73
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(73)] as timestamp) AS FIELD74
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(74)] as timestamp) AS FIELD75
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(75)] as INT64) AS FIELD76
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(76)] as INT64) AS FIELD77
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(77)] as INT64) AS FIELD78
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(78)] as timestamp) AS FIELD79
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(79)] as timestamp) AS FIELD80
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(80)] as timestamp) AS FIELD81
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(81)] as timestamp) AS FIELD82
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(82)] AS FIELD83
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(83)] as FLOAT64) AS FIELD84
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(84)] as FLOAT64) AS FIELD85
safe_cast(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(85)] as FLOAT64) AS FIELD86
from `db.ds.tbl`
```

GBQ states this query is structurally sound. but shows this response:

```
Array index 74 is out of bounds (overflow) google big query
```

How do I respond to this?
Thanks

just to be clear.  the delimiter is `|"||"|`.  for example:

```
6|"||"|Demo (60 Minutes) |"||"|demo60min|"||"|2017-09-13 16:30:00|"||"|2017-09-13 15:30:00
```

Thanks

Comment: There aren't that many elements in the array after splitting it. You need to fix your query or fix the data.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Array index 74 is out of bounds (overflow) google big query
>   How do I respond to this?

Instead of using `[OFFSET(NN)]` in line like below

```
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[OFFSET(NN)]
```

you should use `[SAFE_OFFSET(NN)]` as in below example

```
SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|')[SAFE_OFFSET(NN)]
```

> Extra update

As you can see - your query is quite bulky and hard to read and maintain

Below is simplified example of how to transform your query into compact one

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  SAFE_CAST(item[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS INT64) AS FIELD1,
  item[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS FIELD2,
  item[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS FIELD3,
  item[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] AS FIELD4,
  item[SAFE_OFFSET(4)] AS FIELD5,
  item[SAFE_OFFSET(5)] AS FIELD6,
  SAFE_CAST(item[SAFE_OFFSET(6)] AS TIMESTAMP) AS FIELD7
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST([STRUCT<item ARRAY<STRING>>(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|'))])
```

You can test it with sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '''6|"||"|Demo (60 Minutes) |"||"|demo60min|"||"|2017-09-13 16:30:00|"||"|2017-09-13 15:30:00''' AS RECORDSTRING
)
SELECT 
  SAFE_CAST(item[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS INT64) AS FIELD1,
  item[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS FIELD2,
  item[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS FIELD3,
  item[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] AS FIELD4,
  item[SAFE_OFFSET(4)] AS FIELD5,
  item[SAFE_OFFSET(5)] AS FIELD6,
  SAFE_CAST(item[SAFE_OFFSET(6)] AS TIMESTAMP) AS FIELD7
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST([STRUCT<item ARRAY<STRING>>(SPLIT(RECORDSTRING, '|"||"|'))])
```

with result

```
Row FIELD1  FIELD2              FIELD3      FIELD4              FIELD5                 FIELD6      FIELD7    
1   6       Demo (60 Minutes)   demo60min   2017-09-13 16:30:00 2017-09-13 15:30:00    null        null
```

Comment: what does SAFE_OFFSET get me?

Comment: instead of error - you will just get NULL for absent elements/indexes and whole query will just be completed

Comment: wouldn't that mean I have a bigger problem?

Comment: i just answered your specific question  - if you see other issue(s) and have respective questions  - just post them and we will be happy to further help :o)

Comment: Appreciate it! See extra in my answer! hope will help you in further dev

Comment: well explained. Thanks for the answer.