# Splitting the string into columns to extract values using BigQuery

Tags: sql, regex, split, google-bigquery

How can i split the string by a specific character and extract the value of each. The idea is that i need to extract each word between the line including the start/end of the string as this information represents something. Is there a regex pattern ? or a way to split the info into columns ?

```
Name
A|B|C|D|E|F|G


Name           col1  col2  col3  col4 col5   col6  col7
A|B|C|D|E|F|G   A     B     C     D     E      F    G
```

I am using BigQuery for this and couldn't find a way to get the info of all of those. I tried the regex code which only works for the case where we have A|B|C.

I have to compare each column value and then create conditions using `case when`

CODE:

```
select
  regexp_extract(name, "\\w+\\S(x|y)") as c2, -- gives either x or y
  left(regexp_substr(name, "\\w+\\S\\w+\\S\\w+"),1) as c1, 
  right(regexp_extract(name, "\\w+\\S\\w+\\S\\w+"),1) as c3 
from Table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select *
  from  your_table, unnest(split(name, '|')) value with offset
)
pivot(any_value(value) as col for offset in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

if applied to dummy data as in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: The solution makes total sense as in some cases there might not be 6 name columns and so a null is important there. The solution below doesn't have that feature. I will just have to rename the columns I believe as this can't be done directly ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a use case for SPLIT().

```
select split(name,"|")[safe_offset(0)] as c1, split(name,"|")[safe_offset(1)] as c2, ..
from table
```

see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split

Added use of safe_offset instead of offset per [Array index 74 is out of bounds (overflow) google big query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546549/array-index-74-is-out-of-bounds-overflow-google-big-query)

Comment: in your solution this will fail if the number of columns are not always the same. It returns the error instead of null value

Comment: Touche!  Ok, just use SAFE_OFFSET.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546549/array-index-74-is-out-of-bounds-overflow-google-big-query